# Is there somthing like 'out of scope' in C#? And some related questions

Tags: c#

I am a C#-Newbie.

I have a function that is supposed to return all values from a List, that have the matching time-stamp:

```
static public PointCloud getPointsByTime (float time)
{
    PointCloud returnList = new List<PointData> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < _pointCloud.Count; i++) {
        if (_pointCloud [i].time == time) {
            returnList.Add (_pointCloud [i]);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Where

```
public class PointData
{
    public float time;
    // and some other members
}
```

and

```
// let's call a list of PointData-objects a PointCloud
using PointCloud = System.Collections.Generic.List<PointData>;
```

Does my function do what I want it to do? Or do I have to create a new `PointData`-object? Am I able to use my returned `PointCloud` or will it be out of scope and deleted?

This may be not the best example to explain so feel free to link me to something better. I think you get what my basic quastions are.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the meaning of your last code sample (using PointCloud...). Other than that it looks like your code should work.

Comment: I would be cautious about using floats for timestamps.

Comment: I am using Unity3D and it exports the game time as `float`. That is the reason I did it this way.
`using PointCloud...` is just so I don't have to write `System.Collections.Generic.List<PointData>` everytime.

Comment: It would work but I'm not sure that you are fully aware of the semantics. The returned `PointCloud` would hold *references* to the original entries in `_pointCloud`. If these original entries are changed later, the references in your new list will reflect the changes (since they point to the same Point objects). You can use a struct instead of a class for `Point` -- structs would be copied by value, creating new objects.

Comment: And if you use structs you may want to read these design guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx -- immutable structs are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. You can use your function like so:

```
var someTime = 0.0f;
var pointsAtTime = getPointsByTime(someTime);
DoSomethingWith(pointsAtTime);
```

The return value from the function remains in scope if you assign it to some local variable (e.g. `pointsAtTime` here).

EDIT: As Peter Schneider correctly notes in the comments, you need to be aware that this function creates a new list with **references** to the matching points, and does not create new points. This might or might not be what you want.

---

However, if you're new to C#, here are some things you might want to keep in mind:

1. Methods in C# are conventionally named in TitleCase, e.g. `GetPointsByTime` and not `getPointsByTime`.
2. Assigning names to generic types like `using PointCloud = List<PointData>`, while technically allowed, is not very idiomatic and might confuse other readers of your code. If you think a list of PointData is special enough to have its own type, create a type for it (either by inheriting from `List<PointData>` or, preferably, using a `IList<PointData>` as a member in a new `PointCloud` class). Or just use `using System.Collections.Generic` and use `List<PointData>` throughout your code, which is what most people would do.
3. Comparing floating-point numbers for equality is sometimes discouraged as this might fail in some cases due to representation errors; if the time is truly a continuous value, you might want to look for points in a specific time period (e.g. points who fall within some range around your desired time). You don't really have to worry about this for now, though.

Comment: @Peter Schneider  that's good to know. I am still a little bit confused due to the lack of pointers.

Comment: What do you mean, "lack of pointers"? ;-) It's a big deception, like in Java  -- there are *only*  pointers (called references) unless you make a conscious effort.

Comment: If you're coming from a pointer-oriented background (e.g. C/C++), you can think of all reference types (classes) in C# as being passed as a pointer (i.e. having a `*` next to them all the time), while the value types (the primitives and `struct`s)  are passed by value.

Comment: Its also important to note that `using alias = Type` statements are only processed in the *file in which they are contained*, so if you use an outside class it will look strange. You'll declare the `PointCloud` alias as the return type and when you look at the return type in another file, it'll show up as `List<PointData>`.

Answer (score 4):

As @Patrick suggested inheriting for List seems more reasonable, but I would go further and I would just use a List so you don't create an unnecessary class if it is not going to add anything extra.

Also I suggest you to have a look to LINQ which makes the code more readable and is a very powerful feature that you would like to master as soon as possible. :)

Your method could look then like this:

```
_pointCloud.Where(p => p.time == time).ToList();
```

Also try to get familiar with properties:

```
public class PointData
{
      public float Time { get; set; }
}
```

And you may want to follow the more standard C# coding style (although this is completely personal) of using PascalCase for public members instead of camelCase.

Comment: thanks. this is my real code, I simplified it for this question  
    `private float _time;
 
 public float time {
  get { return _time; }
  set { _time = value; }
 }`

Comment: Unless you want to keep a _time member for something else you don't really need to define the underlying private member of a property. Just using what I suggest will work without adding the extra lines :)

Comment: I am aware of this. I just feel more comfortable with my extra lines and a leading underscore for private members

Comment: Thanks grand then :) I used to do the same but at the end switched to this more minimalist approach :P